# How to better track Indices in java (vs. Python)

Tags: java, python, dictionary

In python you can store various types different items in a list, however accessing them must be done through their respective index or a list method.

With python dictionaries you can map keys to items so as to not have to constantly memorize which index has which item.

Python dictionaries are very easy to write:

```
mydic = {"item1":True, "item2":True, "item3":True}
```

and also easy to acces:

```
if mydic["item1"]:
    localvar = mydic["item1"]
    mydic["item1"] = False
```

Likewise, in Java I have attempted to do the same thing though I have found it much more complicated:

```
//this program assumes the creation of a class and method//
HashMap<String, Boolean> mydic = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
mydic.put("item1", false); mydic.put("item2", false); mydic.put("item3", false);
```

and particularly difficult to access:

```
boolean localvar = mydic.get("item1");
if (localvar){
    mydic.remove("item1");
    mydic.put("item1", false);
} else {
    localvar = null;
}
```

Now I'm not trying to compare languages and if I did, Java would probably win to be honest. It does however seem counter productive to be creating a hashmap of items and values then cast them back into a boolean and then add and remove to change the value to true.

Now in the case of booleans I know there is the option of bitsets but what if the items have say, three possibilities rather than two ie. On/neutral/off?

I considered also the possibility of passing variables around and coordinating with lists
(it would look like this in python)

```
item1, item2, item3 = 0, 1, 2
list = [True, True, True]
def afunction(item1, item2, item3, itemlist):
    itemlist[item1] = False
```

I'm actually not sure if you can even use the syntax
    itemlist[item1] = False 
in java. However I am concerned mostly with the memory requirements and doing things the way
that makes the most sense for java.

Any and all input appreciated,

Comment: Why are you casting `Boolean` to `boolean`?

Comment: Without the cast I was getting errors that type was hashmap.

Comment: [Works fine without the cast.](https://ideone.com/7QYoGP) You must be doing something different.

Comment: well I was accessing it from an object, ie object.mydic.get()

Comment: You left out a closing quote, and you cannot assign 0 to a boolean!

Comment: yeah I was fixing that as you commented :p

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The question is/should be/being changed to: How can I track indices in java?

Comment: you can't assign null to a boolean either--the only acceptable values of a primitive boolean are true and false!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java's syntax is more verbose in this respect than Python's syntax.
There's not much really to answer here. That's just how it is.

This is pretty good/standard way of coding it in the Java world. I don't
see anything wrong with it, or anything that can be simplified too much here.

```
//this program assumes the creation of a class and method//
HashMap<String, Boolean> mydic = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
mydic.put("item1", false); mydic.put("item2", false); mydic.put("item3", false);
```

Regarding this note of yours...

> this program assumes the creation of a class and method

... well, each Java program has at least one class and at least one method, so that's fine too.

Comment: I feel like the syntax necessary defeats the purpose of using the java hashmaps in the way that I am using them. Should I be using lists and tracking the indices some other way?

Comment: No, I think not. If you want to have constant time access to the boolean value given a particular String value, than HashMap mapping String to Boolean is better and simpler too. Your approach is OK IMHO. You're just used to the less verbose Python syntax but in Java terms this code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can use diamond syntax in the declaration:

```
Map<String, Boolean> mydic = new HashMap<>();
mydic.put("item1", false);
mydic.put("item2", false);
mydic.put("item3", false);
```

Your other code is confusing, it should be:

```
if (mydic.get("item1")) {
    mydic.put("item1", false);
}
```

Not sure what `localvar` is doing.

Comment: local var was specifically for the cast, in the case of my program it was being called from an object ie. object.get()

Comment: and I was getting errors saying that it was type hashmap

Comment: @stackoverflow101 sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Eclipse was complaining that the line if (mydic.get("item1")) { was illegal because it was type hashmap and needed to be type list. I can only assume I was getting this error because in the context of my program it would be if (object.mydic.get("item1")) {

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `object.`. This is valid syntax. You may have had some issues with your generics.